# Receive no email when declining

Tags: docusignapi

Here is my scenario :

- an envelope is created through the Java REST API whith one document and two successives signers (step 0)
- Signer A with routingOrder equals to 1 signs the document (step 1)
- Signer B with routingOrder equals to 2 delcines the envelope (step 2).

When I use the acocunt of a colleague, Signer A receives an email when Signer B declines. When I use my personnal account, Signer A doesn't receive any email.

Do you have an idea why ? I checked the configurations of both the accounts but I am unable to find any difference.

Thanks a lot,

EDIT : In my example, neither Signer A nor Signer B are the creator of the envelope. But the results are the same when one of them is the creator.

All the "recipients notifications" checkboxes are activated in my account.

When I use the Web Console instead of the API, both SignerA and Signer B received a notification when Signer B declines. So, no, it's absolutely not the same behaviour as when I use the API. if I could have the behaviour with the API, it would be great !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Captive recipients don't receive decline notification email, since you have selected `"Send completion emails to embedded signers" in your Sender Account's --> Go To Admin --> Signing settings` that's the reason you are getting Completed Notification email for captive/embedded signers. And when you send any envelope from WEB then all signers are remote signers, captive signers are generated only through API, so notifications functionality are different when using WEB and API.

Embedded/Captive Signers receive Initial Email to start Signing if you have populated `"embeddedRecipientStartURL"` in your envelope creation api call, if you don't put `"embeddedRecipientStartURL"` then even initial email will also not sent. Other notification which embedded recipient will receive (id "embeddedRecipientStartURL" set) in any resend done either using API or WEBApp. Embedded Recipients will not receive any notification related to decline, void, reminders or expiry.

Comment: Thanks a lot Amit K Bist ! What you say matches perfectly what I observe with my tests. But do you know any official documentation where this behaviour is decribed, so I chan show it to my client ? Again, thanks a lot !

Comment: There is no official documentation related to email notifications for embedded signing.

Comment: Your answer isn't what I hopped but I'll do with that... Agains, thanks a lot Amit K Bist !

Answer (score 1):

The most likely cause is notification suppression. You will want to log in to your personal account and navigate to My Preferences > Notifications > Recipient Notifications: Check 'Another recipient has declined to sign a document'

To confirm, neither Signer A nor Signer B are the sender of the envelope, right?

Does the same behavior occur when sending via the Web Console instead of the API?

Comment: Thanks Drew for your help. Unfortunately, the checkbox is activated in my account. I answered your other questions by editing my initial post. I you had other idea, I would be really grateful !

Comment: Unless you're setting Signer A to be a Captive Recipient, I'm not sure what else would cause that. I'd recommend opening a case with DocuSign Support and providing an envelope id and the email addresses for the recipients in question.

Comment: If I understand correctly, a signer is said "captive" when you give them a clientUserId, right ? Both of my signers receive a mail from DocuSign to access to our application and then we display DocuSign into an iframe. So, yes both of them are captive. How does it affect the mails after declining ? They still both received a mail when the envelope is completed by all the recipients. Isn't the same mechanism ?